# Concatenate 4th column when Grouping 3 columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Table A that has 4 columns: a, b, c, d. I am grouping columns a, b, and c, and want to display a concatenated value with ',' of d column in 4th column. How do I achieve that?

Comment: So do you mean all possible values of the fourth column shown in a comma delimited list?  Does order, or the number of times each value appears matter?  Should it be a distinct list, or include duplicates?  What are you aggregating or summarizing to group by in the first place?  Is that column included in result set?

Comment: I'm thinking this is not a job for group by.  It almost sounds like you just want a distinct listing of possible combinations of 1st, 2nd, and 3rd columns - combined with a comma delimited list of all the possible values of the fourth.  That would take the shape of two logical selects joined.

Comment: You are right RThomas. Grouping is just for understanding. Duplicates will be fine and order is also not required.

Comment: It's a duplicate of a duplicate....